# Set absolute positioned element width to its content (it is only a text)

Tags: html, css, position, width, absolute

I am going to build this

[image]

This is my HTML code

```
<div class="al-head-container">
    <div></div>
    <span>Center Websites</span>
</div>
```

This is css :

```
.al-head-container{
    margin: auto;
    width: 100%;
    padding:0 4%;
    position: relative;   
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.al-head-container > span{
    font: 2.1em titr;
    color: #ae7f00;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    left:0;

}
.al-head-container > div{
    width: 100%;
    height: 20px;
    background-image: url("../image/head-line.jpg");
    position: relative;
    top: 25px;
}
```

But this is the result of code

[image]

The problem is the `span` width is set to 100% and its width doesn't fit to its content. it is what I get from the firebug

[image]

As you see the text covers the `DIV` that contains the line.

I tried to set the `display:inline-block` for `span` but nothing changed. How do I can make the absolute positioned span width to fit the content?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not accomplish this purely in CSS with a single element:

```css
div {
    border-top:1px solid lightgrey;
    border-bottom:3px solid lightgrey;
    height:2px;
    position:relative;
    margin-top:15px;
}
div:after {
    content:attr(data-label);
    position:absolute;
    top:-10px;
    left:50%;
    padding:0 20px;
    display:inline-block;
    background:#fff;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    text-align:center;
    color:#A37716;
    font-size:24px;
}
```

```html
<div data-label="Center Websites"></div>
```

Comment: Nice I was thinking about a double border but your aproach is awesome, plus 1

Answer (score 1):

I will suggest make a few changes on your code.

- You can remove the `div` element and instead use a `pseudo-element` later with CSS

  ```
  <div class="al-head-container">
      <span>Center Websites</span>
  </div>
  ```
- Then with CSS make the pseudo-element be the absolute one to place it behind the span:

  ```
  .al-head-container{
      position:relative;
  }
  .al-head-container > span{
     font: 2.1em titr;
     position:relative;
     z-index:10;
     display:inline-block;
     padding:0 20px;
     height:2.1em;
     line-height:2.1em;
     color: #ae7f00;
     background-color: #FFFFFF;
  }
  .al-head-container:after{
      content:"";
      width: 100%;
      top:50%;
      transform:translateY(-50%);
      border-top:dotted 3px red;
      position: absolute;
      left:0;
  }
  ```

Check this **[Demo on Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k23q6v8c/)**

---

<sub>Note that you can replace the border on the fiddle with your background image</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```css
.fancy {
  line-height: 0.5;
  text-align: center;
}
.fancy span {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;  
}
.fancy span:before,
.fancy span:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 5px;
  border-bottom: 3px solid gray;
  border-top: 1px solid gray;
  top: 0;
  width: 600px;
}
.fancy span:before {
  right: 100%;
  margin-right: 30px;
}
.fancy span:after {
  left: 100%;
  margin-left: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="subtitle fancy">
    <span>Center Websites</span>
</div>
```

Also here you have a working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tblancog/L6wf4r8y/)

Answer (score 0):

try to add margin auto on absolute span

```
.al-head-container > span{
    font: 2.1em titr;
    color: #ae7f00;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    left:0;
    margin : auto;
}
```